# Given a list of coordinates, find all within radius of single point

Tags: mobile, gis

I am trying to figure out the best way to list all points of interest within a certain radius of a specified centre point (current location).

My app currently retrieves all locations from our related web api.

Which would be best, to create an api call to return locations that are close by or to calculate that information in my app?

My concern is that the mobile device could be overwhelmed by this calculation if the list of points gets very large in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're looking at mobile scenarios, I'd suggest doing it on the web service side. The bandwidth will be a much larger bottleneck than computation time of finding the nearby points so reducing the number of points transferred will be better for the majority of cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about the math behind it, they way you calculate is as follows:

1- Suppose the center node coordinates are (N_x,N_y)

2- Suppose every point of interest such as *i* have the coordinates of (i_x,i_y)

The distance between the center point and the point of interest is yield:

d = sqrt((N_x-i_x)^2+(N_y-i_y)^2))

you will list those that d < r

where r is the radius.